# Solving the limit that involves exponential and power

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the following limit $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}e^{-ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}}.$$ where $a,b,c$ are positive constants.

My Attempt:

I can use the series formula for exponential to have following form $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left[1+ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}+.5\left(ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}\right)^2+(3!)^{-1}\left(ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}\right)^3+.....\right]^{-1}$$ but unfortunately I do not even know how to solve the very second term in this series. I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sqrt { 2^{b+c/x} - 1}$ is not defined for small negative $x.$

Comment: Shouldnt it be $0^+$

Comment: edited according to your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x \to 0^+$. Then roughly speaking, as $y = c/x \to \infty$, the $b$ and $-1$ become insignificant:

$$e^{-ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}} \sim \exp\left(-ax \sqrt{2^{c/x}}\right) = \exp\left(-ac \frac{\sqrt{2^{y}}}{y}\right).$$

Note that $\sqrt{2^{y}} = 2^{y/2}$ grows much faster than $y$ (since it's exponential) and hence

$$\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2^{y}}}{y} = \infty.$$ Therefore,

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\exp\left(-ac \frac{\sqrt{2^{y}}}{y}\right) = e^{-\infty} = 0 = \lim_{x\to0^+}e^{-ax\sqrt{2^{b+c/x}-1}}.$$

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: can we say that $y\exp{(-ac\frac{2^{y/2}}{y})}$ and $y^2\exp{(-ac\frac{2^{y/2}}{y})}$ also approaches to zero as $y\to \infty$?

Comment: @FrankMoses Yes, this works in your other question. The exponential term "overpowers" the linear and quadratic terms.

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised that you know my other question. However, can we prove it mathematically?

Comment: @FrankMoses Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369773/what-is-the-limit-x-to-infty-of-xn-cdot-e-x

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to show that $x\sqrt {2^{b + c/x} -1}\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+.$