# How to find the value of $e^{-x} x^n$ at x = $\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function, infinity

How to find the value of $e^{-x} x^n$ at x = $\infty$ ? Actually while proving that $\Gamma(n+1) = n\Gamma(n)$ there is a step where I need to evaluate  ($e^{-x} x^n$)$\big|_0^\infty$ . Now, since this is not an improper integral but the expression after calculating an improper integral(by parts) for which I need to find the value by substituting upper and lower limit, I donot know how to calculate the value at infinity since infinity is not a finite value. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is just a standard limit, which can be evaluated using L'Hopitals rule or using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369773/what-is-the-limit-x-to-infty-of-xn-cdot-e-x)

Comment: Are you aware that $O(e^x)>O(x^n)$ as $x\to\infty$ for all $n$?

Comment: Regarding your other question, which is legitimate: you don't calculate the *value* at $\infty$, but the *limit* at $\infty$. To see why, do the integration by parts on $[0,A]$ and *after that* let $A\to\infty$.

Comment: @epiliam What is  $O$ here ?

Comment: It's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. It's how fast it grows as $x\to\infty$. For example $O(3x) = O(\sqrt{x^2-3})$. My point was that $e^x\to\infty$ faster than any polynomial so we must have that $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x} x^n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a result that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p(x)}{e^x} = 0$ for any polynomial $p(x)$. You can see this intuitively looking at Taylor's Series expansion of $\exp(x)$.

Then, $$\frac{x^n}{e^x} |_0^\infty = \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{e^\alpha} - \frac{0}{1} = 0. $$

Otherwise, you could use L'Hopital since numerator and denominator are going to $\infty$ and are continuous and differentiable in all $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential growth is faster than polynomial.  L'hopital's rule gives $0/e^x\to0$, when applied repeatedly.