# Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{2\lg{n}}}}{\lg^2(n)}$ is infinity

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am trying to prove that $2^{\sqrt{2\lg{n}}}$ is asymptotically larger than $\lg^2(n)$ so that    $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{2\lg{n}}}}{\lg^2(n)}=\infty$.

I have learned that $2^ \sqrt{2\lg n}=n^ \sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{\lg n}\right)}$ but apart from that I was unable to get any closer to the proof. All I am thinking of currently is to find a useful approximation that will make the limit evident, but still no such identity comes to my mind.

So the question is how to prove this

Edit: lg represents logarithm with base 2

Comment: What is $\operatorname{lg}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x^2 = 2\log_2(n)$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{2\log_2(n)}}}{(\log_2(n))^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2^x}{\frac{x^4}4}$$

then use that eventually $2^x=e^{x\log 2}\ge x^5$ or as an alternative L'Hospital's rule.

Refer also to the related

- [What is the limit $x\to\infty$ of $x^n \cdot e^{-x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1369773/505767)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the easiest way is always to express them in **canonical form** so that they can be easily compared. For exponentiation, always express it using the same base. Here, you have $2^{\sqrt{2·\lg n}}$ and $(\lg n)^2 = 2^{2·\lg\lg n}$. Can you tell which is bigger? If not, just do one more step of the canonicalization process: $\sqrt{2·\lg n} = \sqrt{2}·2^{1/2·\lg\lg n}$ and $2·\lg \lg n = 2·2^{\lg\lg\lg n}$. Now there are no more exponents, and obviously $1/2·\lg\lg n ≫ \lg\lg\lg n$ as $n → ∞$.

Note that this process is completely systematic, and computer algebra systems use such processes to evaluate limits. For related systematic limit computations, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2504179/21820) and the posts linked from there.